# Windows 8 phone app crashes on open when location services are off

Tags: c#, api, xaml, windows-phone-8, geolocation

I have a weather app which takes the users location in latitude and longitude and then uses a api to give back the results. Once the location services are turned off, the app crashes on open and gives no error help to see where the error is. Is there a way to write an if statement to see if location services are one? What should I do to prevent this issue?

Here is the code:

```
 async private void GetLocation()
        {
            var geolocator = new Geolocator();
            if (geolocator.LocationStatus == PositionStatus.Disabled)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("We need your current location for the app to function properly, please set location services on in settings");
                MessageBoxResult mRes = MessageBox.Show("We need your current location for the app to function properly, please set location services on in settings", "I understand", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
                if (mRes == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {
                    Application.Current.Terminate();
                }
                if (mRes == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
                {
                    Application.Current.Terminate();
                }
            }

            Geoposition position = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
            Geocoordinate coordinate = position.Coordinate;
            latitude = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(coordinate.Latitude, 2));
            longitude = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(coordinate.Longitude, 2));

            URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&units=metric";

            Client(URL);
        }

public void Client(string uri)
        {
            var clientToken = new WebClient();
            clientToken.OpenReadCompleted += clientToken_OpenReadCompleted;
            clientToken.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(uri));
        }
```

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

To determine where the error is occurring check your error stack traces logged by Microsoft from your Windows Dev Center - https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-US/CrashReport ("Export top stack traces from the last 30 days" link above graph).

There may be a delay for stack traces showing up. [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com/) is a very useful tool that will give you great error reports to help with debugging. Only takes one line of code to get up and running in your app to catch unhandled exceptions.

With BugSense you can also add "breadcrumbs" which are added to your error reports. You can then check from locations services being turned on yourself and add this information to help you figure out the issue from the exceptions stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when Location is turned off, it throws an exception which you are not handling in a try/catch block.Here is the sample code from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to handle this properly:

```
private async void OneShotLocation_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if ((bool)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LocationConsent"] != true)
    {
        // The user has opted out of Location.
        return;
    }

    Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
    geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50;

    try
    {
        Geoposition geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(
            maximumAge: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
            );

        LatitudeTextBlock.Text = geoposition.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString("0.00");
        LongitudeTextBlock.Text = geoposition.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString("0.00");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if ((uint)ex.HResult == 0x80004004)
        {
            // the application does not have the right capability or the location master   switch is off
            StatusTextBlock.Text = "location  is disabled in phone settings.";
        }
        //else
        {
            // something else happened acquring the location
        }
    }
}
```

You should visit the [Source MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) article and read it for better understanding. This sample is at Step 7.